# VBA Range statement using active column

Tags: excel, vba, range

I need to use my active column in my range statements. How to write down this:

```
Range((Activecolumn)2)
```

So I need a column value to be dynamic because I am moving left and right by pressing a userform button, but the row number always stays the same. At first I am working with column "C" and select it with

```
Columns("C").Select
```

and I navigate the selected column with

```
Private Sub Next_Format_Button_Click()

ActiveCell.Offset(, 1).EntireColumn.Select

End Sub
```

So when I navigate to the next column I need all my other range statements to go along with it. So basically the column letter in my range statements should be something like "current" or "active" column.

Could someone, please, help me?

Comment: Do you just need a variable where you get the number of the column you are in?

Comment: Just use `Cells(2, activecell.column)`

Comment: That is what I was looking for but in this example I was looking for "C1"not "C2" so that "2" in the code should be "1". But besides that - it's what I needed

Comment: How would it look if my rows range is "C4:C6" because "Cells(4:6, ActiveCell.Column)" seems to be incorrect as it highlights red in VBA editor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Range(ActiveCell.address).entireColumn.copy
```

Is what you are looking for I think?

I'd also recommend avoiding ".Select" unless absolutely necessary. It is adding unnecessary lines to your code and leaves the program at greater risk of inadvertent user corruption by selecting another range via mouse before the copy (or whatever) operation completes. Better to go straight to whatever operation you intend to do, or by assigning the range to a variable.

edit: Ah, sorry, I see now your only looking row 2, then its Cells(2, ActiveCell.Column) as pointed out above.

Comment: There's no possibility to accidentally select wrong place in the sheet as all the actions are happening in the userform and changes are instantly propagated to the sheet. Sheet has disabled editing and all that, but it's handy to see the active column selected from user standpoint

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the Number of the column where you selected something:

```
ActiveCell.Column
```

If you need the letter of the column your selection is in:

```
Split(ActiveCell.Address, "$")(1)
```